# How to send integer through NSOutputStream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstream

So I'm making an iOS app that constantly sends and array of points through `NSStream`s, but because sometimes the sender writes two arrays before the receiver receives one, I decided to first write the length, then the array data itself, so that the receiver knows how many bytes to process.

sender:

```
if (_outStream && [_outStream hasSpaceAvailable]){
    const uint8_t *buffer = [data bytes];
    uint64_t length = CFSwapInt64HostToLittle([data length]);
    NSLog(@"Sending bytes with length: %llu", length);
    int er1 = [_outStream write:(const uint8_t *)&length maxLength:sizeof(length)];
    int er2 = [_outStream write:buffer maxLength:length];  
    if (er1 < 0 || er2 < 0) {
        [self _showAlert:@"Failed sending data to peer"];
    }
}
```

receiver:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        if (stream == _inStream) {
            uint8_t *b;
            int len = 0;
            len = [_inStream read:b maxLength:8];
            uint64_t dataLength = CFSwapInt64LittleToHost(*b);
            NSLog(@"Received bytes with length: %llu", dataLength);
            if(len < 0) {
                if ([stream streamStatus] != NSStreamStatusAtEnd)
                    [self _showAlert:@"Failed reading data from peer"];
            } else if (len > 0){
                uint8_t bytes[dataLength];
                int length = [_inStream read:bytes maxLength:dataLength];

                [currentDownload appendBytes:bytes length:length]; 
                 id pointsArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:currentDownload];
                [currentDownload release];
                currentDownload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                if ([pointsArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                    [drawScene addNewPoint:[[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue] previousPoint:[[pointsArray objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue]];
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

The problem is that the receiver receives an incorrect integer, hence it reads an incorrect amount of bytes.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that when you read the data, you're starting with the introductory bits intended to convey length, rather than starting with the actual data?

For:

```
[currentDownload appendBytes:bytes length:length];
```

try substituting something like this:

```
NSRange rangeLeftover = NSMakeRange(sizeof(uint8_t), [currentDownload length] - sizeof(uint8_t));
NSData *dataLeftover = [currentDownload subdataWithRange:rangeLeftover];
uint8_t bytesLeftover[[dataLeftover length]];
[dataLeftover getBytes:&bytesLeftover length:[dataLeftover length]];
currentDownload = [NSMutableData data]; // clear
[currentDownload appendBytes:bytesLeftover length:[dataLeftover length]];
```

Comment: No its not that. I'm checking the integer that is being send aswel as the one that is coming in. And those mismatch.

Comment: But you're sending 2 distinct sets of info: an int representing the length of the answer, followed by the int (or ints) that is the answer itself. If you retrieve the answer data starting at bit 0 of what has come in, you are actually including the introductory "length" bits as part of the "answer" int bits, and the result would then be a mismatch. A good test would be to send an answer that is simply 1.

Comment: I get your point, but that isnt the problem at hand. The very first int that is being send is also misread. If i fix that. i could easily use it to start reading bytes at a later point (if that is necessary).

Comment: Oh, so the "incorrect integer" is actually the length. Can you tell us what the length should be and what is actually being read? That might provide a clue. Does the length exceed 8 bits?

Comment: Nop, the length being send is 388 and the receiving int displays 137.

Comment: 8 bits can only accommodate decimal 0 through 255. 388 is binary 110000100, which is 9 bits. You probably should be using type uint16_t for your length instead of uint8_t.

Comment: It doesnt work that way: I have to send a pointer of type uint8_t (Which can be the start of a array).

Comment: The data a pointer points to can't exceed the number of bits represented by its datatype. So your buffer "b", of datatype uint8_t, can't exceed 8 bits. You're also specifying "maxLength:8" when you read from the stream into the buffer. So "dataLength" will never be anything above 255.

Comment: Pardon, the maxLength arg is bytes, not bits, so you're probably erring in the opposite direction there. But I double-checked, and uint_8t is 8 bits. Your buffer is not big enough.

Comment: @Wienke I replaced both with sizeof(uint8_t) * 4. but it still doesnt work,  i also added int to bytes conversion and vice versa:

Comment: `- (uint8_t *)convertToBytes:(int)i {uint8_t *retVal = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 4);
    retVal[0] = i >> 24;
    retVal[1] = i >> 16;
    retVal[2] = i >> 8;
    retVal[3] = i >> 0;
    return retVal;
}

- (int)convertToInt:(uint8_t *)i {
    int retVal = 0;
    retVal += i[0] << 24;
    retVal += i[1] << 16;
    retVal += i[2] << 8;
    retVal += i[3] << 0;
    return retVal;
}
`

Comment: Hmm. So “b” could point to the first element of an array of uint8_ts, convertible to anything via bitwise operations  — if you initalized it via your convertToBytes method. But you don’t use that method or malloc directly in your code. “b” is never allocated any particular block of memory. I’ll bet that’s the problem.

Comment: Hmm *b has the correct bytes (after the write it ends up as the same array as that was being send) only the conversion back isnt working (returns abnormal large number).

Comment: Got it working! I was sending the pointer value's to the write method instead of the values itself. Got it to work with my methods. Thank you for your help!